# Package 'flameshot' not opening on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

Successfully installed the package 'flameshot' from 'software center'of Ubuntu. Icon visible. Getting displayed on 'launcher'and taskbar. Clicked on it to open. It is taking time to open, then disappear and does not open.

Uninstalled the package. Please help and guide how can I make it working?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of which package you installed and from where. Did you install the apt (debian) version or the snap might be useful to gaiin some help as well as the commands used to run it.

Comment: Please run `flameshot` in a terminal and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Add `gui` at the command-line or launcher, as shown in the screenshots below.

[image: Launcher command]

[image: Terminal command]

Comment: And how do you do that? A screenshot of a properties page we don't know how to access isn't helpful

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when installing via SNAP. (Ubuntu 20.04)

Error:

```
$ flameshot \
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
```

Solution:

```
$ unset SESSION_MANAGER
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. It was showing

```bsh
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
```

when I was trying to open:
`flameshot configure`
also, app was crashing when trying to save an image.
But, removing the package `sudo snap remove flameshot` and installing directly from the Ubuntu Store fixed my issue.